# Optimal way of separation of data from a list

Tags: python, web-scraping

Based on one website, which contains statistical information, I have implemented basic web scraping code and here it is:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
content = requests.get("https://www.geostat.ge/ka/modules/categories/26/samomkhmareblo-fasebis-indeksi-inflatsia")
content = BeautifulSoup(content.content, 'html.parser')
#print(content.prettify())
information = []
for row in content.select('tbody tr'):
    for data in row.find_all('td'):
        if len(data.text.strip()) != 0:
            information.append(data.text.strip())
print(information)
```

It returns the following information:

```
['2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2016', '2017', '2018', '2019', '2020', '2021', '2022', '2023', 'საშუალო წლიური წინა წლის საშუალო წლიურთან', '99.1', '99.5', '103.1', '104.0', '102.1', '106.0', '102.6', '104.9', '105.2', '109.6', '111.9', '102.5', 'დეკემბერი წინა წლის დეკემბერთან', '98.6', '102.4', '102.0', '104.9', '101.8', '106.7', '101.5', '107.0', '102.4', '113.9', '109.8', '100.4'
```

Now the first part before the text is containing 'საშუალო' year, and the rest of them are inflations between the two texts, so I have implemented this very manual code:

```
years = []
average_annual = []
december = []

first_index = information.index('საშუალო წლიური წინა წლის საშუალო წლიურთან')
second_index = information.index('დეკემბერი წინა წლის დეკემბერთან')
for i in range(0, first_index):
    years.append(int(information[i]))
print(years)
for  i in range(first_index + 1, second_index):
    average_annual.append(float(information[i]))
print(average_annual)
for i in range(second_index + 1, len(information)):
    december.append(float(information[i]))
print(december)
```

It shows the correct separation:

```
[2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023]
[99.1, 99.5, 103.1, 104.0, 102.1, 106.0, 102.6, 104.9, 105.2, 109.6, 111.9, 102.5]
[98.6, 102.4, 102.0, 104.9, 101.8, 106.7, 101.5, 107.0, 102.4, 113.9, 109.8, 100.4]
```

Is there a more optimal way of doing this?

I have tried this version:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_html("https://www.geostat.ge/ka/modules/categories/26/samomkhmareblo-fasebis-indeksi-inflatsia", encoding='utf-8')[0])
#data.drop(0, axis=0, inplace=True)
#data = data.droplevel(level=0, axis=1)
print(data)
```

And it returns this result:

```
                                          0       1   ...      11      12
0                                        NaN  2012.0  ...  2022.0  2023.0
1  საშუალო წლიური წინა წლის საშუალო წლიურთან    99.1  ...   111.9   102.5
2            დეკემბერი წინა წლის დეკემბერთან    98.6  ...   109.8   100.4

[3 rows x 13 columns]
```

How can I handle this case?

Comment: What is *"inflations between the two texts"*? (Not a rhetorical question.)

Comment: sorry i did not get  question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this site I recommend using `pandas.read_html` to read the table into a dataframe. But first you can rename first row as header (`<th>`) to get correct column names:

```py
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = '"https://www.geostat.ge/ka/modules/categories/26/samomkhmareblo-fasebis-indeksi-inflatsia"'
content = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")

for td in soup.tr.select("td"):
    td.name = "th"

df = pd.read_html(StringIO(str(soup)))[0]
df = df.set_index(df.columns[0])
df.index.name = None

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                           2012   2013   2014   2015   2016   2017   2018   2019   2020   2021   2022   2023
საშუალო წლიური წინა წლის საშუალო წლიურთან  99.1   99.5  103.1  104.0  102.1  106.0  102.6  104.9  105.2  109.6  111.9  102.5
დეკემბერი წინა წლის დეკემბერთან            98.6  102.4  102.0  104.9  101.8  106.7  101.5  107.0  102.4  113.9  109.8  100.4
```

Comment: wow, it is great answer, by thr  way what is application of StringIO?

Comment: @dato [`pandas.read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) needs as an argument file-like object, so StringIO creates one from string.

Comment: when i have  used  your code, it generate this error : requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '"https://www.geostat.ge/ka/modules/categories/26/samomkhmareblo-fasebis-indeksi-inflatsia"'

Comment: @dato Try to add `https://` in front of the string

Comment: if i directly  use read_html and  then format pandas

Comment: @dato Yes, read my answer - first read the page using `beautifulsoup`, then rename first row `td` to `th` and after that use `read_html`

Comment: i mean without useing Beautifulsoup is it possible?

Comment: @dato Of course, you can manipulate dataframe afterwards, but that is other question. Feel free to open new question here on StackOverflow

Comment: ok i iwll do it and post link here

Comment: here it is my friend : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78143589/read-html-without-beautifulsoup