# read_html without Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, pandas

based on my previous question : [optimal web parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78143411/optimal-way-of-seperation-data-from-list/78143462?noredirect=1#comment137764301_78143462)

i have got nice solution, but let us suppose that i am explaining this  part to my students from economic diriection, they dont know too much about web parsing, so i have decided to use directly read_html and got folloing result :

```
data =pd.DataFrame(pd.read_html("https://www.geostat.ge/ka/modules/categories/26/samomkhmareblo-fasebis-indeksi-inflatsia",encoding='utf-8')[0])
# data.drop(0,axis=0,inplace=True)
# data =data.droplevel(level=0,axis=1)
print(data)


                                        0       1   ...      11      12
0                                        NaN  2012.0  ...  2022.0  2023.0
1  საშუალო წლიური წინა წლის საშუალო წლიურთან    99.1  ...   111.9   102.5
2            დეკემბერი წინა წლის დეკემბერთან    98.6  ...   109.8   100.4
```

as you see there is additional level on the top of year, how can i handle this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame(
    pd.read_html(
        "https://www.geostat.ge/ka/modules/categories/26/samomkhmareblo-fasebis-indeksi-inflatsia",
        encoding="utf-8",
    )[0]
)

header = data.loc[[0], :]  # first row of the dataframe will be the new header
data = data.loc[1:, :]  # the rest will be new data

data.columns = ["", *header.loc[0, 1:].astype(int)]  # rename columns (first column will be empty string, the rest integers (years))

print(data)
```

Prints:

```
                                              2012   2013   2014   2015   2016   2017   2018   2019   2020   2021   2022   2023
1  საშუალო წლიური წინა წლის საშუალო წლიურთან  99.1   99.5  103.1  104.0  102.1  106.0  102.6  104.9  105.2  109.6  111.9  102.5
2            დეკემბერი წინა წლის დეკემბერთან  98.6  102.4  102.0  104.9  101.8  106.7  101.5  107.0  102.4  113.9  109.8  100.4
```

Comment: both of them are similar  according difficulties, any  way  they could not memoried it that why i am  teaching them  to  get use with googling

Comment: @dato If somebody wants to learn beautifulsoup, pandas, ... one needs to use Google. But this solution is not hard, it's basically just slicing the dataframe to two parts - header, data

Comment: yes i have tried it myself  and use line by line  , it is just experiment